# environment variables in jupyter notebook? (osx)

Tags: python, macos, environment-variables, jupyter-notebook

i'm trying to put together a technical notebook for a python project that involves some YouTube scraping, so i want to set the developer key as a behind-the-scenes environment variable.

i know how to do this with virtual environments for terminal scripts, but it's not working in jupyter notebook.

i have an 'env_vars.sh' file in anaconda3/etc/conda/activate.d that reads as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

export DEVELOPER_KEY='keytextgoeshere'
```

and when i load jupyter, it doesn't show up in `print(os.environ.keys())` ... same goes when i try `!source activate` for environments i know have other variables. adding text to ~/.bash_profile also didn't work. (i'm loading the right kernel, i swear!)

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you found an answer?